# How to extract Data from Django Queryset

Tags: django, django-models

How to retrieve the data from Django queryset for use in a variable

When an output is received in below form after running the query

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'John'}]>
```

I want to use the value 'John' in a variable for further processing.

How do I extract this ?

Comment: But this is a *collection* of values, so it is, stricty speaking possible that this queryset contains zero, one, or more entries. If you filter such that there is always exactly one element, you should use `Model.objects.get(pk=my_pk)`.

Comment: Thanks Willem, So I am using filter and it may get me more than one names. So given the above format of output, How do I get the names out of it  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
k = <QuerySet [{'name': 'John'}]>
k[0] = {'name': 'John'}
```

Queryset is a list.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `values_list()`.

```
myValues = myQuerySet.values_list()
```