# Extract only the data from a Django Query Set

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am working to learn Django, and have built a test database to work with.  I have a table that provides basic vendor invoice information, so, and I want to simply present a user with the total value of invoices that have been loaded to into the database.  I found that the following queryset does sum the column as I'd hoped:

```
total_outstanding: object = Invoice.objects.aggregate(Sum('invoice_amount'))
```

but the result is presented on the page in the following unhelpful way:

**Total $ Outstanding: {'invoice_amount__sum': Decimal('1965')}**

The 1965 is the correct total for the invoices that I populated the database with, so the queryset is pulling what I want it to, but I just want to present that portion of the result to the user, without the other stuff.

Someone else asked a similar question (basically the same) here:  [how-to-extract-data-from-django-queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815303/how-to-extract-data-from-django-queryset), but the answer makes no sense to me, it is just:

> k = k[0] = {'name': 'John'}
>
> Queryset is list .

Can anyone help me with a plain-English explanation of how I can extract just the numerical result of that query for presentation to a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you here get is a dictionary that maps the name of the aggregate to the corresponding value. You can use *subscripting* to obtain the corresponding value:

```
object = Invoice.objects.aggregate(
    Sum('in,voice_amount')
)['invoice_amount__sum']
```